# SQL. How to extend a table using date?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I use SQL 2008.

I have a logical entity (table) say Data with attributes (columns) (key, date, a,b,c,d).

the problem is a and b change values every day and that c and d change values at random dates and very slow. And also they change for each key individually. Say c,d for key = 1 will change today and next month and for key=2 tomorrow and a week later.

So my idea is to split on 2. MainData (key,date,a,b) and TemporalData (key, changeDate, c,d)

However I failed to write an efficient query - how to consume this.

I was thinking of somewhat a 'parametrized' view (not sure if it is possible at all). Say select * from vwData where date = 'xxxxx' and it will return me a,b for that particular day and also c,d which were effective for a particular key and that date.

**I need a simple and clear way to select data from this construct. I also need it to be efficient as data will be huge in a year time**

*(Note: there will be only select where date = @singleDate never date between)*

Example:

```
MainData             TemporalData
1 20101001 1.0 2.0   1 20101001 2.0 3.0
1 20101002 2.0 3.0   1 20101003 8.0 9.0
1 20101003 4.0 5.0   
1 20101004 6.0 3.0   

 select * from vwData where date = '20101002'

 1 20101002 2.0 3.0 2.0 3.0

 select * from vwData where date = '20101003'

 1 20101003 4.0 5.0 8.0 9.0

 select * from vwData where date = '20101004'

 1 20101004 6.0 3.0 8.0 9.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, splitting the data into a 1:1 relationship with more static data in one table and data that changes often in another table is not a bad approach. Second, it is not clear whether TemporalData.ChangeDate should match MainDate.[Date]. Assuming that is the case, then you can do something like so:

```
Select MainData.Key, MainData.[Date], MainData.a, MainData.b
    , TemporalData.c, TemporalData.d
From MainData
    Left Join TemporalData
        On TemporalData.Key = MainData.Key
            And TemporalData.ChangeDate = MainDate.[Date]
Where MainData.[Date] = @SomeDate
```

This assumes you will always have MainData values but might not have TemporalData values. You could put this in a view however you could not specify a parameter. A view is a virtual table and as such represents an unordered set of rows. Thus, your view would look like:

```
Create View vwMain 
As
Select MainData.Key, MainData.[Date], MainData.a, MainData.b
    , TemporalData.c, TemporalData.d
From MainData
    Left Join TemporalData
        On TemporalData.Key = MainData.Key
            And TemporalData.ChangeDate = MainDate.[Date]
```

You would then use the view like so:

```
Select ...
From vwMain
Where [Date] = @SomeDate
```

**EDIT**

It would appear that what you want is to always have a TemporalData row representing the the most recent date. This is not clear from your description although we can deduce it from your comments and sample output. So, given that, here's a solution. Obviously, the final result would not include the common-table expressions for the sample source data:

```
With MainData As
    (
    Select 1 As [Key], '20101001' As [Date], 1.0 As A, 2.0 As B
    Union All Select 1 As [Key], '20101002', 2.0, 3.0
    Union All Select 1 As [Key], '20101003', 4.0, 5.0
    Union All Select 1 As [Key], '20101004', 6.0, 3.0
    )
    , TemporalData As
    (
    Select 1 As [Key], '20101001' As [ChangeDate], 2.0 As C, 3.0 As D
    Union All Select 1 As [Key], '20101003', 8.0, 9.0
    )
    , RankedResults As
    (
    Select MainData.[Key], MainData.[Date], MainData.a, MainData.b
        , TemporalData.c, TemporalData.d, TemporalData.ChangeDate
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By MainData.[Key], MainData.[Date]
                          Order By TemporalData.ChangeDate Desc ) As Num
    From MainData
        Join TemporalData
            On TemporalData.Key = MainData.Key
               And TemporalData.ChangeDate <= MainData.[Date]
    )
Select *
From RankedResults
Where Num = 1
Order By [Date]
```

Comment: Thomas. the whole problem is that main.date will be for every day but temporal.date will be for very few dates hence your select will produce nulls for all main.dates except those which are queal temporal.dates...

Comment: @Bobb - Not true. I'm using a Left Join to TemporalData. Thus, I'll get every MainData row and only the matching rows from TemporalData.

Comment: Exactly. I will get date, a,b,null,null for days between ChangeDate for a key.... so... How I am supposed to get c and d ? This is the whole point of the question to get latest available c and d for the DATE AND KEY

Comment: @Bobb - What you failed to make clear in your original post is that you *always* want a TemporalData row. Specifically, the temporal data row from the last date if there isn't one that matches the current date.

Comment: @Bobb - Your description says nothing of this requirement. We can however deduce it from the sample output.

Comment: if you replace the part of your answer with the scripts below (I added data for Key 2) it stops to work..... I really like the way you think :) but i need workable solution

Comment: ( 
    Select 1 As [Key], '20101001' As [Date], 1.0 As A, 2.0 As B 
    Union All Select 1 As [Key], '20101002', 2.0, 3.0 
    Union All Select 1 As [Key], '20101003', 4.0, 5.0 
    Union All Select 1 As [Key], '20101004', 6.0, 3.0 
    Union All Select 2 As [Key], '20101001', 6.0, 3.0 
    Union All Select 2 As [Key], '20101002', 2.0, 3.0 
    Union All Select 2 As [Key], '20101003', 4.0, 5.0 
    Union All Select 2 As [Key], '20101004', 6.0, 3.0 
    )

Comment: @Bobb - Noticed I missed including Key in the Join. Have fixed.

Comment: @Bobb - Btw, if you want to add additional sample data, modify your original post. That helps other readers.

Comment: @Bobb - What should happen if there are no temporal rows for the given Key?